# Why is 'this' equal to 'Window' in my prototype function?

Tags: javascript

I have a `prototype` function written on the `Array` class like

```
Array.prototype.myfunc = () => 
{
   // ... 
}
```

and within the body `this` is referring to `window` when I call it on an array like

```
var result = [1, 69, -1, 1].myfunc();
```

How can I make it refer to the array on which it's being invoked?

Comment: Why do you use lambdas BTW? They're still not supported by many browsers.

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `() => { }` arrow syntax binds to the current `this` which likely is `window` (depending on when you assign the function).

Answer (score 2):

The fat arrow syntax in ES6 is an implicit bind to the current scope.

If your current scope is `Window` (or the global scope), then the function you just set on the prototype is bound to that scope.

You still need the good ol' `function ()` syntax for behavior without binding.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use arrow function here, arrow function inherits context from the parent scope.

```
Array.prototype.myfunc = function() {
   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's causing your issue is **the use of an arrow function**.

**In arrow functions**, the **`this`** keyword may reference to:

1. **window** (if accessed globally, not in strict mode),
2. **undefined** (if accessed globally, in strict mode),
3. **an instance** (if in a constructor),
4. **an object** (if in a method or function inside an object or instance) or
5. **a binded/applied value**.

To fix your issue, you have to use a "normal" `function()` and you can call your function using **`call(this, ...params)`**:

- In `this` you put **the object you want the keyword `this` to be bound to** and
- In `..args` you put **your function's parameters** if any.

So, with the above in mind, your code can be as shown:

```
Array.prototype.myfunc = function(...) {
   // Your code
}

var array = [1, 69, -1, 1];
var result = myfunc.call(array, ...);
```

- Using **`array`** as the first argument in **`call()`**, you bind the **`this`** keyword to **`array`**.